# Attach file to form on redirect

Tags: php, file, redirect, laravel

Im providing a file preview option, where the user attaches a file, and then clicks preview.
Which uploads the file, and outputs a PHPExcel preview.

From that page, I want to include a button that says continue.
Which will then proceed with the actual upload and database row creation.

However once I redirect to the preview page, I have no idea how to attach this file to my hidden form for resubmission.

I can attach all the old input values....like so...
But how do I attach the file???  (using blade in laravel for templating)

```
/* These work and are correct*/
<input type="text" id="xlsColumnOrder" name="xlsColumnOrder" value="{{$input['xlsColumnOrder']}}"/>
<input type="text" name="researcher" value="{{$input['researcher']}}" />    
<input type="text" name="leadcity" value="{{$input['leadcity']}}" />
<input size="16" id="survey_date" name="survey_date" type="text" value="{{$input['survey_date']}}"  /> 
/* This doesnt attach anything to the file input
/*  Need to attach the previously uploaded file here for resubmission */                                 
<input class="file" id="csvfile" name="csvfile" type="file" value="{{$file['csvfile']['tmp_name']}}" />
```

Comment: you can't do that. values of `<input type='file'>` can only be selected by the users, never programmatically set.

Comment: So is there another solution??  How can i re-upload this file?  I know I can store it on the server and refer to it like that, but I dont have that choice since Im using appfog, and they dont have persistant file storage

Comment: Its a security feature to prevent you from sneakily choosing to steal any file from the user that you want. File upload requires user interaction. And even if you could do it, do you really want to upload the file to your server multiple times from the client's machine?  That's a waste of bandwidth. You need to rethink the design.

Comment: For instance, put all the other inputs on the first pages, and the file on the last page that finalizes the transaction.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason Im not just simply putting it on the server is because appfog doesnt have persistant file storage, so I dont have a choice, unless I use Amazon S3 or something.  But I figured there might be an easier way

Comment: I can't do that, because I need to provide a visual preview of the files / column layout for confirmation first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot automatically resend user files so I would do it this way:

- When user sends form if any file is provided you save file in some directory (you treat it as temporary) and save file name/names to session and show user preview of file
- When he clicks continue - you can do with other data whatever you want (for example save it to database or show as hidden in another form) and you still have uploaded filename in session so if you want you may even again show file preview
- When you want to finally save all user data you move user file/files to final directory (and possible rename it) and save all the data with file(s) name (probably in database).

As addition you should have some kind of cron that removes data from your temporary directory that very created for example more than 3 hours

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I ended up doing.  The only reason I was trying to avoid it was because AppFog doesnt have persistant file storage, so I wasnt able to store the file anywhere.  But I ended up just using Amazon S3.  Store the file temporarily, view it, and when they actually submit it, it automatically deletes the file after.  Its gold now :)